# Is this indicator function continuous?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact topological space and $U$ an open subset of $X$. Consider
$$Y:= (\overline{U} \times \{0\})\cup (U^c \times \{1\}) \subseteq X \times \{0,1\}.$$

Is the indicator function $\chi_{U^c \times \{1\}}: Y \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous? I argued as follows:

This indicator function is continuous if and only if the boundary of $U^c \times \{1\}$ is empty. But the boundary of $U^c \times \{1\}$ is equal to $(U^c \cap \overline{U})\times \{1\}$, which is possibly non-empty. For instance, consider
$$U = (0,1), X = [0,1] \implies U^c \cap \overline{U}= \{0,1\}$$
so I seem to be able to conclude that in general $\chi_{U^c \times \{1\}}$ is not continuous. Is this correct?

**Edit**: Maybe I'm supposed to endow $Y$ with the disjoint-union topology, as opposed to the (relative) product topology. Does this make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X \times \{0,1\}$ actually has the same topology as a disjoint union of two copies of $X$ (if $\{0,1\}$ is discrete which I asume is the intention) so the last part is moot.

$\chi_A$ is continuous iff $A$ is clopen (both closed and open) and that need not be the case for $Y$, indeed, only if $U$ were already clopen. $\partial Y = \partial U \times \{0,1\}$ in fact.

Comment: Note that $\chi_{U^c \times \{1\}}$ is actually continuous, when we view it as a function on $Y$!